# Is it possible to recover parts of values of any layer in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using deeplab V3 structure for an image task, but I make a slight change that add a channel at input. So that the first CNN layer becomes [7,7,4,64] instead of [7,7,3,64].

I plan to do transfer learning, so I hope to recover all parameters except for the fourth channel of this first CNN layer, but these four channels are mastered by one tf.Variable so that I don't know how to recover them by tf.train.Saver. (tf.train.Saver can control which tf.Variable should be recovered but not some values of any tf.Variable I think)

Any idea?

---

Some codes related are shown below:

1. Load function

```py
def load(saver, sess, ckpt_path):
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt_path)
```

2. Part of main function

```py
# All variables need to be restored
restore = [v for v in tf.global_variables()]

# Set up tf session and initialize variables
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config = config)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess.run(init)

# Load Variables
loader = tf.train.Saver(var_list = restore)
load(loader, sess, args.restore_from)
```

In main function, we can see that recovered variables are controlled by 'restore'. In this case, the first entry of 'restore' is:

```
<tf.Variable shape=(7,7,4,64) dtype=float32_ref>
```

But what I only hope to recover is the first three channels from another model, which is with size (7,7,3,64). And initialize the last channel with a zero initializer.

Any function can help with this?

Comment: Please enter your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've put some codes already. If not detailed enough, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible quick hack could be, instead of creating a variable with the new shape and trying to convert parts of it over, just creating a variable with the part that's missing (so shape=[7,7,1,64]) and concatenating it with your variable and using that as the convolution kernel.

For transfer learning to work properly, this should be zero-inited instead of random variables (which should be fine because the other values break the symmetry), or initialized with values that are very small compared to the pretrained ones (assuming the new channel has the same range of values), otherwise the later layers won't see the distributions they expect.

Comment: Nice reply. Thanks!